# New predictions in polynomial regression

Tags: r, regression, prediction, poly

I got the following regression model and I am trying to do some predictions, but I always get an error:

```
model1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length +  poly(Sepal.Width, 2), data = iris)
predict(model1, model1$model)
```

> Error in poly(Sepal.Width, 2, coefs = list(alpha = c(3.05733333333333,
>   :  object 'Sepal.Width' not found

I know I could simply access the fitted values for the predictions. 
But let's say my new data looks like this:

```
newdata <- head(model1$model) + 1
```

How can I do predictions on this new data set, without getting this error?

Comment: Read the documentation: `help("predict.lm")`.  `newdata` has to have the same column names as `data` passed to `lm`. That's obviously not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the `model` slot from your `lm` object, which does not contain the original data but the matrix, where the polynomial part is already expanded:

```
head(model1$model)
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Length poly(Sepal.Width, 2).1 poly(Sepal.Width, 2).2
# 1          5.1          1.4            0.083201357           -0.016039377
# 2          4.9          1.4           -0.010776079           -0.053252127
# 3          4.7          1.3            0.026814895           -0.056361540
# 4          4.6          1.5            0.008019408           -0.057805919
# 5          5.0          1.4            0.101996844            0.009397687
# 6          5.4          1.7            0.158383306            0.121697905
```

This does not work of course, because `predict` wants to have a `Sepal.Width` column. You can provide a proper data argument:

```
predict(model1, head(iris[, 1:4]) + 1)
#       1        2        3        4        5        6 
# 6.306370 5.845728 5.973836 5.979895 6.406965 6.868732
```

Comment: Yes I know, but let's assume I don't have the actual dataset available. I just used iris as an example

Comment: I think I don't quite get your question then. For which data set you want to get predictions for? If it is the original one, use `fitted(.)` if it is any other you can provide it yourself.

Comment: @user11143533 Are you looking for `cbind(1, as.matrix(model1$model)[,-1]) %*% coef(model1)`? This will give you the fitted values and could be adapted for prediction with a new matrix.